# Java:Android - EdiText's number minus another EditText number?

Tags: java, android

So basically im wondering how I can take an EditText input (Numbers) minus the other EdiText input.

For example if I type "10" in the first EditText and then "5" in the second, I want it to calculate 10-5 and then print it out in a TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String s1 = txt1.getText().toString(); // "10"
String s2 = txt2.getText().toString(); // "5"

int i1 = Integer.ParseInt(s1);
int i2 = Integer.ParseInt(s2);

int i3 = i1 - i2;

txt3.setText(String.valueOf(i3));

Answer (score 0):

You can get the EditTextValue in string format and then you can do

```
try {
   int diff = Integer.parseInt(EditTextValueInString.trim()) - Integer.parseInt(EditTextValueOFOtherInString.trim());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   // This is because your input to parse int was not a valid number do what ever you want to do when it fails.
}
```

Comment: important to check if what is inside edittext is a number (or it will throw an exception) (or use inputType:number to try to force it)